db2 Temp Table Multiple Values and Rows
I'm currently writing an SQL Script for Work. I want to store multiple Values in a temp_table with specific Columns. Later in the script I want to refer to the columns with a case. I Also want to refer to those columens with a specific row and i don't know how.
This what I have for now:
CREATE TABLE ##temp_table 
(
    NUMBER3 integer, 
    NUMBER4 integer, 
    NUMBER5 integer, 
    NUMBER6 integer, 
    NUMBER7 integer, 
    NUMBER8 integer, 
    NUMBER9 integer
);

INSERT INTO ##temp_table (NUMBER3, NUMBER4, NUMBER5, NUMBER6, NUMBER7, NUMBER8, NUMBER9)
VALUES ('10003','10004','10005','10006','10007','10008','10009'),
('20003','20004','20005','20006','20007','20008','20009'),
('30003','30004','30005','30006','30007','30008','30009'),
('40003','40004','40005','40006','40007','40008','40009'),
('50003','50004','50005','50006','50007','50008','50009'),
('60003','60004','60005','60006','60007','60008','60009'),
('70003','70004','70005','70006','70007','70008','70009'),
('80003','80004','80005','80006','80007','80008','80009');

-- SELECT * FROM ##temp_table -- View the Table
--

SELECT A.MEMBER,
B.GENDER,
B.BIRTHDATE,
...
...
...
C.MEMBER_NR,
CASE 
    WHEN C.MEMBER_NR = t.ANZAHL3 THEN '3'
    WHEN C.MEMBER_NR = t.ANZAHL4 THEN '4'
    WHEN C.MEMBER_NR = t.ANZAHL5 THEN '5'
    WHEN C.MEMBER_NR = t.ANZAHL6 THEN '6'
    WHEN C.MEMBER_NR = t.ANZAHL7 THEN '7'
    WHEN C.MEMBER_NR = t.ANZAHL8 THEN '8'
    WHEN C.MEMBER_NR = t.ANZAHL9 THEN '9'
    ELSE NULL
END AS NUMBER_MEMBERS,

Now a Dummy-Code
CASE -- Dummy-Code
    WHEN C.MEMBER_NR = t.ANZAHL3 in Row 3 THEN 'New'
    WHEN C.MEMBER_NR = t.ANZAHL3 in Row 5 THEN 'Old'
    ELSE NULL
END AS MEMBERS_Status,
...
...
--

FROM ....
    
CROSS JOIN ##temp_table AS t
    
WHERE ...

DROP TABLE ##temp_table;


You are aliasing your temp table as T which has columns  number3, 4 etc..  But in your case using AHZAHL3?  Is that the same as number3 in your temp table?

In pure relational theory there is no such thing as a "row number" since the rows have no natural order. So if you want to refer to a rownumber you would have to add a separate column for it.

Yes, the MEMBER_NR is the same Number equal the Numbers in Colum ANZAHL3... 4 etc. Or was the step of declaring the temp_table as t wrong?

@piet.t yes, i found the solution by adding ROWID integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), thanks :)
